# How to convert character with comma into numbers in Sparklyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I use spark_read_csv to read the raw data into Spark but one field was character?

"110,000.00"

I want to convert it into number since it means dollar amount but had hard time to decode it correctly? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: In R that'd be fairly simple with `as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", x))`, is there something in how it is read-in or available that you cannot use that?

Comment: Try `quote = FALSE` when you read the file.

Answer (score 1):

`sparklyr` uses "HIVE" syntax [check here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), any of those Hive functions should work within a `dplyr` verb so in order to perform this particular string transformation you need to use something like `REGEXP_REPLACE`

here is the answer to your question, I included the details so everything is clear

```
my_test_df = data.frame(char_val = "110,000.00")

my_test_spark = my_test_df %>%  copy_to(sc, ., 'my_test_df_spark' )

my_test_spark 

# Source: spark<my_test_df_spark> [?? x 1]
#  char_val  
#  <chr>     
#  1 110,000.00

my_test_spark %>%  
  mutate(my_new_char = regexp_replace(char_val, ',','')) %>%  
  mutate(my_numeric = as.numeric(my_new_char)) %>% 
  head 


# # Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
# char_val   my_new_char my_numeric
# * <chr>      <chr>            <dbl>
# 1 110,000.00 110000.00       110000
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do it is to use `stringr` package to remove the comma and then convert the string to numeric.

```
library(stringr)
numbers <- c("100,000.00", "200,000.00")
numbers <- str_replace_all(numbers, ",", "")
numbers <- as.numeric(numbers)
```